# Leaf nodes in tikz-qtree are not aligned with parents when using grow=left

Tags: tikz-qtree

I am building a rotated tree using tikz-qtree. Whenever i use the setting "grow=left", the leaf nodes will be shifted a constant distance compared to their parent nodes, so that the lines between them aren't vertical.
This does not seem dependent on the rotation.

Is there any way to avoid it? :)

My code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=left, sibling distance=5pt,rotate=90,transform shape]
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=275pt}}
\Tree [ 
    [tip1 ]
    [
        [tip2 ]
        [
            [
                [tip3 ]
                [
                    [
                        [tip4 ]
                        [
                            [tip5 ]
                            [tip6 ]
                        ]
                    ]
                    [
                        [
                            [tip7 ]
                            [tip8 ]
                        ]
                        [
                            [
                                [tip9 ]
                                [tip10 ]
                            ]
                            [
                                [tip11 ]
                                [tip12 ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [
                [tip13 ]
                [
                    [tip14 ]
                    [
                        [
                            [tip15 ]
                            [tip16 ]
                        ]
                        [
                            [
                                [tip17 ]
                                [tip18 ]
                            ]
                            [
                                [tip19 ]
                                [tip20 ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Dendogram}
\label{fig:dendogram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And the resulting figure is:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead, edit your question to include the fragment in a compilable minimal document that people can play with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `tikz-qtree` aligns the `base` anchor of the leaf nodes with the corresponding parent node if there is only one branch. Then, it draws the branch connecting the parent node to the `center` anchor of the leaf node. This works for vertical trees, but causes misalignment for horizontal trees.

To solve this, add

```
every leaf node/.append style={anchor=center}
```

to the options of your `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=left, sibling distance=5pt, rotate=90, transform shape, every leaf node/.append style={anchor=center}]
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=275pt}}
\Tree [ 
    [tip1 ]
    [
        [tip2 ]
        [
            [
                [tip3 ]
                [
                    [
                        [tip4 ]
                        [
                            [tip5 ]
                            [tip6 ]
                        ]
                    ]
                    [
                        [
                            [tip7 ]
                            [tip8 ]
                        ]
                        [
                            [
                                [tip9 ]
                                [tip10 ]
                            ]
                            [
                                [tip11 ]
                                [tip12 ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [
                [tip13 ]
                [
                    [tip14 ]
                    [
                        [
                            [tip15 ]
                            [tip16 ]
                        ]
                        [
                            [
                                [tip17 ]
                                [tip18 ]
                            ]
                            [
                                [tip19 ]
                                [tip20 ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Dendogram}
\label{fig:dendogram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Begs for `forest`, though ;).

Answer (score 4):

hm, your dendogram can be translated to `forest` as:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{forest}
for tree = {
    s sep=0pt,
    if n children=0{rotate=90,anchor=east,tier=word}%
                   {coordinate}
            }
[
    [[tip1]]
    [
        [[tip2]]
        [
            [
                [[tip3]]
                [
                    [
                        [[tip4]]
                        [
                            [[tip5]]
                            [[tip6]]
                        ]
                    ]
                    [
                        [
                            [[tip7]]
                            [[tip8]]
                        ]
                        [
                            [
                                [[tip9]]
                                [[tip10]]
                            ]
                            [
                                [[tip11]]
                                [[tip12]]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [
                [[tip13]]
                [
                    [[tip14]]
                    [
                        [
                            [[tip15]]
                            [[tip16]]
                        ]
                        [
                            [
                                [[tip17]]
                                [[tip18]]
                            ]
                            [
                                [[tip19]]
                                [[tip20]]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\caption{Dendogram}
\label{fig:dendogram}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any significant advantages of using forest over tikz-qtree?

Comment: @user43228, `forest is dedicated for drawn trees. It is very powerful, ... however in your particular case as you can see, in code between them is no big difference. I wrote answer as response to cfr comment :-)